# Rails xml to hash nested attr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I have xml with nested attributes like

```
    <Flight AssociationID="F17462" Source="PN">
 and 
    <FareBasisCode PriceClass="FUN">X1/FUN</FareBasisCode>
```

when i try convert it to hash with `Hash.from_xml(my_xml)`

it gives me only first keys `Flight` without `AssociationID`

I want to have `['Flight']['AssociationID']` etc

Is it possible to do in such way?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [XmlSimple](http://xml-simple.rubyforge.org). You should be able to do:

```
require 'xmlsimple'
config = XmlSimple.xml_in(my_xml)
```

and that should work exactly as you want it to. While there was a [PR to Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/588) that solved the issue you are having, it was not merged. If XmlSimple does not solve your issue, you can try [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org), but that is probably more than you really need.